# Searching for a file is being rejected by the program

Tags: c

I am new to this site and thought it might be a good idea to try to ask if anyone knows what the problem can be with this code becuase it doesn´t find a file that is already existing. Now, I have tried changing the `"wb"` and `"rb"` since I am out of ideas (lol) also making sure that every line isn´t making something funny becuase i dont get any errors.

When I run this program I add a person with a name and number and then I want to be able to search for the person in two different ways (name and number) in this case it´s with the number. The results I have got is always and message "error" which basically means "File cannot be found".

If something is unclear or if I have missed something let me know and I will do my best to make sure its done correctly and by the rules of the page. Thanks!

Comment: What is `t.PN`? The members of the structure are `name` and `number`. And you don't use `==` to compare strings, you need to use `strcmp()`.

Comment: The `error` message doesn't mean "File not found", it means that the number wasn't found in the file. If you want to know if the file was found, you need to check whether `fopen()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Where do you define `fname`? Additionally, the `mode` parameter accepts the following: `"r"`, `"r+"`, `"w"`, `"w+"`, `"a"`, `"a+"`. Try checking for errors at every `fopen`, `fread`, `fflush`, etc, or even better use a debugger, to find exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: You can't compare an `int` with a `char[]` array. You either need to read a string from  the user and use `strcmp()`, or parse `t.number` into a number. Or maybe you should store it as an `int` in the file in the first place.

Comment: There is code missing from this post.  Please post a [mcve].  i.e., is the stuff you have posted actually surrounded my the `main(void){...}` construct?  Are the variables that are not defined in this code, actually defined in your real code.  (this as is will not compile).

Comment: Honestly, there are so many problems with what you've posted that it's almost impossible to help you. It should be getting lots of compiler errors and warnings. Fix all those things and then try to debug it.

Comment: @ryyker sorry for that though it was better to show the problem I knew of instead of uploading the entire code but I have updated it now and hope it´s good enough

Comment: @BillyBrown I use the VS17 debugger and i haven´t got any errors from it even with the highest level possible

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for that i have tried to make it a little clearer on what everything is by uploading the entire file now and I hope it will not show any errors when debugging

Comment: Almost all your `scanf()` calls are wrong.

Comment: They all get the warning: `warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[1000]'`. You shouldn't put `&` before `f.name`, `f.lastname`, etc.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried your edit of the code and at least for me it doesn´t work, maybe I have missed something?

Comment: It's almost certainly not your only problem. There's way too much code here for anyone to bother looking for all the problems. You have a debugger? Use it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `%s` format to read `f.no`. It's an integer, use `%d`.

Comment: `if (f1.name == name)` and `if (f1.program == program)` both produce the warning: `warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('char *' and 'int')`

Comment: Why is it `int name;`?

Comment: And also `int program;`. These should be strings, not integers.

Comment: And as I mentioned before, you can't use `==` to compare strings. This is basic C.

Comment: You added your code, then you removed your code. Why have you removed your code???

Answer (score 0):

There are too many errors, both syntactical and logical to mention. Suggest you learn to use your debugger, but the following code identifies several issues. Look for in-line comments, and follow the suggestions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct emp
{
    char name[1000];
    char lastname[1000];
    char number[1000];
    char gender[1000];
    char program[1000];
    char age[1000];
    char email[1000];
    int no;
};

void search();
void save();
void load();
void add();
void modify();
void delete();

char mygetch();

char fname[] = { "mydb.dat" };

int main()
{
    int ch;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("1. add\n");
        printf("2. Modify\n");
        printf("3. delete\n");
        printf("4. Search\n");
        printf("5. load\n");
        printf("6. Save\n");
        printf("7. Exit\n");

        printf("Enter one number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1: add();
                break;
            case 2: modify();
                break;
            case 3: delete();
                break;
            case 4: search();
                break;
            case 5: load();
                break;
            case 6: save();
                break;
            case 7: exit(0); /// suggest changing this to "return 0;"
        }
        mygetch();
    }

    return 0;  /// Warning: will never be executed.
}

char mygetch()
{
    char YN;
    char f1;

    scanf("%c", &f1);
    scanf("%c", &YN);

    return (YN);
}

void add() {
    struct emp f;
    FILE *text;

    text = fopen(fname, "ab"); // should test "text" for NULL.  If NULL, exit with error
    printf("Enter name:\n");
    scanf("%s", &f.name);   /// when working with strings, "&" is not needed (same for all remaining
    printf("Enter last name:\n");
    scanf("%s", &f.lastname);
    printf("Enter age:\n");
    scanf("%s", &f.age);
    printf("Enter gender:\n");
    scanf("%s", &f.gender);
    printf("Enter email:\n");
    scanf("%s", &f.email);
    printf("Enter program:\n");
    scanf("%s", &f.program);
    printf("Enter personal number:\n");
    scanf("%s", &f.number);
    fwrite(&f, sizeof(f), 1, text);  /// also incorrect arguments, need several calls, one for each string to write:
                                     /// eg: fwrite(f.name, sizeof(f.name), 1, text);


    fclose(text);
}
void save()
{
    struct emp f1;
    FILE *text, *File1;

    char YN[10], name[51];


    printf("Want to make a copy of the file?\n");
    scanf("%s", YN);

    if (strcmp(YN, "Y") == 0)
    {

        printf("Enter the new file name that should be saved:\n");
        scanf("%s", name);

        text = fopen(name, "wb");
        File1 = fopen(fname, "rb");

        while (1)
        {
            fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1);

            if (File1)
            {
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text); /// also incorrect arguments, need several calls, one for each string to write:
                                              /// eg: fwrite(f.name, sizeof(f.name), 1, text);
            break;
        }

        fclose(text);
        fclose(File1);

        remove(fname);

        strcpy(fname, name);
    }
    else
    {
        remove(fname);
    }
}
void modify()
{
    FILE *text, *File1;
    struct emp f1, f;   /// warning: unused variable f1;  (remove it from this function only)
    int no, found = 0, count = 0; /// warning: unused variable count;  (remove it from this function only)

    text = fopen(fname, "rb");
    File1 = fopen("data.dat", "wb");

    printf("Enter the student No. you want to modify:");
    scanf("%d", &no);

    while (1)
    {
        fread(&f, sizeof(f), 1, File1); //invalid argument.  Use fread(f.number, sizeof(f.number)...

        if (feof(text))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (f.no == no)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Enter No:\n");
            scanf("%s", f.no);
            printf("Enter name:\n");
            scanf("%s", f.name);
            printf("Enter last name:\n");
            scanf("%s", f.lastname);
            printf("Enter age:\n");
            scanf("%s", f.age);
            printf("Enter gender:\n");
            scanf("%s", f.gender);
            printf("Enter email:\n");
            scanf("%s", f.email);
            printf("Enter program:\n");
            scanf("%s", f.program);
            printf("Enter personal number:\n");
            scanf("%s", f.number);
            fwrite(&f, sizeof(f), 1, File1); /// also incorrect arguments, need several calls, one for each string to write:
                                             /// eg: fwrite(f.name, sizeof(f.name), 1, text);
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&f, sizeof(f), 1, File1);  /// also incorrect arguments, need several calls, one for each string to write:
                                     /// eg: fwrite(f.name, sizeof(f.name), 1, text);

        }
    }
    fclose(text);
    fclose(File1);

    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("Sorry No Record Found\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        text = fopen(fname, "wb");
        File1 = fopen("data.dat", "rb");

        while (1)
        {
            fread(&f, sizeof(f), 1, File1);

            if (feof(File1))
            {
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&f, sizeof(f), 1, text); /// also incorrect arguments, need several calls, one for each string to write:
                                            /// eg: fwrite(f.name, sizeof(f.name), 1, text);

    }
    fclose(text);
    fclose(File1);
}
void load()
{
    char sentence[1000], filename[100], ch;
    FILE *text, *Newfile;

    printf("Enter a new file name with .dat in the end:\n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    text = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (text == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter a sentence that should overwrite the existing information:\n");
    scanf("%s", &sentence);
    printf("%s\n", sentence);
    fclose(text);

    text = fopen(filename, "r");
    printf("Enter the file name where all the information will be overwritten by the last sentence:\n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    Newfile = fopen(filename, "w");
    while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(text); /// Warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: "int" to "char"
                          /// fix by changing "ch" to type `int`

        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        else
            putc(ch, Newfile);
    }

    printf("Overwritten has been successfully done!\n");
    system("pause");
    fclose(text);
    fclose(Newfile);

    exit(0);
}
void search()
{
    FILE *text, *File1;
    struct emp f1, f;
    int count = 0, found = 0, x; /// warning: unused variable count;  (remove it from this function only) 

    text = fopen(fname, "rb");
    File1 = fopen("data.dat", "wb");

    printf("Choose the way to search for a student:\n");
    printf(" 1. Personal number\n 2. Name\n 3. Program\n 4. Statistics\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);


    if (x == 1)
    {
        char number[1000];
        printf("Enter the personal number that you want to modify:\n");
        scanf("%s", &number);  // string, do not use "&"

        while (1)
        {
            fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text); /// should always test and use return value for functions that provide it
                                             /// in this case, contains the number of elements successfully read. 
                                             /// If an error occurs, fread returns 0 and sets errno to a nonzero value.
                                             /// This would remove need for feof test below.

            if (feof(text))
            {
                break; // remove execution flow from the loop
            }
            if (f1.number == number)
            {
                found = 1;
                printf("Enter students personal number:\n");
                scanf("%s", &f.number);    // string, do not use "&"
                printf("Enter student Name:\n");
                scanf("%s", f.name);
                printf("Enter last name:\n");
                scanf("%s", f.lastname);
                printf("Enter student age:\n");
                scanf("%s", f.age);
                printf("Enter program:\n");
                scanf("%s", f.program);
                printf("Enter student No.:\n");
                scanf("%s", f.number);
                printf("Enter email:\n");
                scanf("%s", f.email);
                printf("Enter gender:\n");
                scanf("%s", f.gender);

                fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text); /// also incorrect arguments, need several calls, one for each string to write:
                                                 /// eg: fwrite(f.name, sizeof(f.name), 1, text);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1); /// also incorrect arguments, need several calls, one for each string to write:
                                     /// eg: fwrite(f.name, sizeof(f.name), 1, text);
                break;
            }
            break; ///Warning: will never be executed.  remove it
        }
        if (found == 0)
        {
            printf("File can not be found.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            text = fopen(fname, "w");
            File1 = fopen("data.dat", "r");

            while (1)
            {
                fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text);
                fflush(stdin);

                if (File1) {
                    break;
                }
                fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1); /// also incorrect arguments, need several calls, one for each string to write:
                                     /// eg: fwrite(f.name, sizeof(f.name), 1, text);
                break;
            }
            fclose(File1);
            fclose(text);
        }
    }
    if (x == 2)
    {
        int name;
        printf("Enter the student name that you want to modify:\n");
        scanf("%d", &name);  /// need "%s" format specifier

        while (1)
        {
            fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text);

            if (feof(text))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (f1.name == name)
            {
                found = 1;

                printf("Enter student Name:\n");
                scanf("%s", &f.name);
                printf("Enter last name:\n");
                scanf("%s", f.lastname);
                printf("Enter student age:");
                scanf("%s", f1.age);
                printf("Enter program:");
                scanf("%s", f1.program);
                printf("Enter personal number:");
                scanf("%s", f1.number);
                printf("Enter email:");
                scanf("%s", f1.email);
                printf("Enter gender:");
                scanf("%s", f1.gender);

                fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text); // see other comments (for all fwrite calls)
                break;
            }
            else {
                fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1);
                break;
            }
            break; ///Warning: will never be executed.  remove it
        }
        if (found == 0) {
            printf("File can not be found.\n");
        }
        else {
            text = fopen(fname, "wb");
            File1 = fopen("data.dat", "rb");

            while (1)
            {
                fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text);
                fflush(stdin);

                if (File1) {
                    break;
                }
                fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1);
                break;
            }
            fclose(File1);
            fclose(text);
        }
    }
    if (x == 3)
    {
        int program;
        printf("Enter the student program that you want to modify:\n");
        scanf("%d", &program);

        while (1)
        {
            fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text);

            if (feof(text))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (f1.program == program)
            {
                found = 1;
                printf("Enter student number:\n");
                scanf("%d", &f1.no);

                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Enter student Name:\n");
                scanf("%s", f1.name);
                printf("Enter last name:\n");
                scanf("%s", f.lastname);
                printf("Enter student age:");
                scanf("%s", &f1.age);
                printf("Enter program:");
                scanf("%s", &f1.program);
                printf("Enter personal number:");
                scanf("%s", &f1.number);
                printf("Enter email:");
                scanf("%s", &f1.email);
                printf("Enter gender:");
                scanf("%s", &f1.gender);

                fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text);
                break;
            }
            else {
                fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1);
                break;
            }
            break;  ///Warning: will never be executed.  remove it
        }
        if (found == 0) {
            printf("File can not be found.\n");
        }
        else {
            text = fopen(fname, "wb");
            File1 = fopen("data.dat", "rb");

            while (1)
            {
                fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text);
                fflush(stdin);

                if (File1) {
                    break;
                }
                fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1);
                break;
            }
            fclose(File1);
            fclose(text);
        }
    }
    if (x == 4)
    {

        text = fopen(fname, "rb");

        printf("Showing all students statistics\n");

        while (1)
        {
            fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text);

            if (feof(text))
            {
                break;
            }
            printf("Student number:\n");
            printf("%d\n", &f.no);
            printf("Student name is:\n");
            printf("%s\n", f.name);
            printf("Student last name is:\n");
            printf("%s\n", f.lastname);
            printf("Student age is:\n");
            printf("%s\n", f.age);
            printf("Student personal number is:\n");
            printf("%s\n", f.number);
            printf("Student program is:\n");
            printf("%s\n", f.program);
            printf("Student gender is:\n");
            printf("%s\n", f.gender);
            printf("Student email is:\n");
            printf("%s\n", f.email);
        }
        fclose(text);

    }
    fclose(File1);
    fclose(text);
}
void delete()
{
    FILE *text, *File1;
    struct emp f1, f;  /// Warning: unused variable "f".  Remove it
    int no, count = 0, found = 0;  /// Warning: unused variable "count".  Remove it

    File1 = fopen("data.dat", "wb");
    text = fopen(fname, "rb");

    printf("Enter the student number that should be deleted:\n");
    scanf("%d", &no);

    while (1)
    {
        fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, text);

        if (feof(text))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (f1.no == no)
        {
            found = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1);
        }
        printf("File has been deleted\n");
        break;
    }
    fclose(text);
    fclose(File1);

    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("File not found.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        text = fopen(fname, "wb");
        File1 = fopen("data.dat", "rb");

        while (1)
        {
            fread(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1);

            if (feof(File1))
            {
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&f1, sizeof(f1), 1, File1);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(text);
    fclose(File1);
}
```